# Vimium highlighter doesn't catch the Google or Facebook login buttons (nor does Konqueror)

Tags: feature-request, bug, login, browser-support, opera

The large red and blue <kbd>Google</kbd> and <kbd>Facebook</kbd> buttons that you see in the very center of the login page aren't detected by Vimium's <kbd>f</kbd> binding, as well as by KDE's Konqueror link-catcher, toggled by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. I realize this might be a bug in the abovementioned products, but twice in a row may be more than a mere coincidence.

P.S. Wanted to use the `</kbd>` tag for a long while. :)